# @Inject does not work with spring 5 jersey 2.29.1, but @Autowire does

Tags: spring, jersey, payara

I have a web app that is using JSF Spring5 Jersey2.29.1 (spring-jersey5) running on Payara 5.1.3.
The DI part is handled by Spring and it`s using @Inject.

My problem is that since I have migrated from Jersey2.25 Spring-Jersey4 and Payara 4.1.9.2 on jersey endpoints I cannot use @Inject for spring beans, I have to use @Autowired.
The error that I receive is:

```
    Severe: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private my.company.rest.internal.workflowengine.LeaveFlowEndpoint.myService
```

I guess it has something to do with the library that is performing the injection(HK2) which when using @Inject is trying to resolve the dependency itself instead of looking for it into spring.
If instead I use @Autowired works like a charm.

Any idea why do I get this ?

PS hk2 version is 2.29.1

web.xml config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>         
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.company.endpoints.rest</param-value>   
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do I have to use other(spring-aware) class here :

```
 <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

?

Comment: Because you haven't setup Spring/Jersey integration correctly. The `@Inject` here isn't processed by Spring, where ``@Autowired` is. So you probably endup with 2 instances of the bean one managed by Jersey and one by Spring.

Comment: updated the question with web.xml config

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to the fact that when deploying to Payara the implicit cdi flag was not disabled. As soon as it was disabled it was ok.